# CardView not fully Scrollable on my fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-scrollview

I am using a fragment to display cardview and a common Bottomnavigation for all fragments. Here I have more than 5 cards as per my data but I am not able to scroll to see all cards. only scrollable up to the second card and the second one is also not fully visible due to the bottom navigation.
main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff293353"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_tab_style"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then Recycleview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/left_enabled"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:id="@+id/btn_normal"
                android:text="@string/normal"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btn_cognitive"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/right_disabled"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/cognitive"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then cardview content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/cardstyle"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

   >

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#3f4865"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    >
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt_recordTitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                        android:paddingStart="12dp"
                        android:text="Normal Test 01"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_card_walk" />

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/parameter1"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                                        android:letterSpacing="0.12"
                                        android:text="No: of gait cycles"
                                        android:textColor="#cecece"
                                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/p1_value"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                                        android:letterSpacing="0.16"
                                        android:text="Details"
                                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                                </LinearLayout>


                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                                    android:layout_height="40dp"

                                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"

                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_card_walk" />

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/parameter2"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                                        android:letterSpacing="0.12"
                                        android:text="Stride Length"
                                        android:textColor="#cecece"
                                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/p2_value"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                                        android:letterSpacing="0.16"
                                        android:text="Details"
                                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                                </LinearLayout>


                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_card_walk" />

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/parameter3"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                                        android:letterSpacing="0.12"
                                        android:text=" Gait time"
                                        android:textColor="#cecece"
                                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/p3_value"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                                        android:letterSpacing="0.16"
                                        android:text="p2"
                                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                                </LinearLayout>


                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5"
                            android:background="@drawable/info_button_style"
                            android:orientation="vertical">


                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:text="@string/total_n_gait_score"
                                android:textAlignment="center"
                                android:textColor="#FFF" />

                            <FrameLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center">


                                <ProgressBar
                                    android:id="@+id/card_progressBar"
                                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
                                    android:indeterminate="false"
                                    android:max="100"
                                    android:progress="65"
                                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/card_progress" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/text_progress"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:text="60%"
                                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
                            </FrameLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>


                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:id="@+id/card_date"
                        android:text="date"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textSize="1sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="time"
                        android:id="@+id/card_time"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please check my code and help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong in your main_activity.xml for fragment `android:layout_above="@id/nav_view"`, it is used for RelativeLayout. Instead use `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"`. This will solve your second issue(the second one is also not fully visible due to the bottom navigation).

Change your `ScrollView` to `NestedScrollView`.

In your cardview content you don't need ConstraintLayout, LinearLayout is sufficient as root element (remove ConstraintLayout as you are not utilising its power of flat view hierarchy). And if your LinearLayout background can be moved to background for MaterialCardView then you don't need LinearLayout too.

For your recyclerview set the `nestedScrollingEnabled` to `false` either through xml or by code. Try these things, it will solve your problem.